# How to convert a list to Map to get the necessary values?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a `geocoding: ^2.0.4` plugin that gives me a list of addresses from coordinates, All I want is the street name  and sublocality

This is the code that prints out the result

```
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
              pointManual2!.latitude, pointManual2!.longitude);
          print(placemarks);
```

and this is the output

```
I/flutter ( 4451): [      Name: Kathmandu,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Street: BHIMSENGOLA 32,
I/flutter ( 4451):       ISO Country Code: NP,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Country: Nepal,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Postal code: 44600,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Administrative area: Bagmati Province,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Subadministrative area: Kathmandu,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Locality: Kathmandu,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Sublocality: New Baneshwor,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Thoroughfare: ,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Subthoroughfare: ,       Name: Sinamangal Road,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Street: Sinamangal Rd,
I/flutter ( 4451):       ISO Country Code: NP,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Country: Nepal,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Postal code: 44600,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Administrative area: Bagmati Province,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Subadministrative area: Kathmandu,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Locality: Kathmandu,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Sublocality: New Baneshwor,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Thoroughfare: Sinamangal Road,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Subthoroughfare: ,       Name: Bhimsengola,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Street: Bhimsengola,
I/flutter ( 4451):       ISO Country Code: NP,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Country: Nepal,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Postal code: 44600,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Administrative area: Bagmati Province,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Subadministrative area: Kathmandu,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Locality: Kathmandu,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Sublocality: New Baneshwor,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Thoroughfare: ,
I/flutter ( 4451):       Subthoroughfare: ,       Name: New
```

what I tried

```
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
              pointManual2!.latitude, pointManual2!.longitude);
          print(placemarks);
var data = placemarks as Map?;
          String name = data?["Sublocality"];
          print("sublocality " + name);
```

Error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<Placemark>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>?' in type cast
```

Do I need to convert it to map? If I were to how could I do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I find your data to be incorrect as it is not of the type `List<Placemark>` as given when declaring the variable.

But, to get a `Placemark`'s properties like `Sublocality`, you should access that placemark on the index of List.

So, for 0th item, as in your case, it feels there's only one item, use this:

```
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
              pointManual2!.latitude, pointManual2!.longitude);
          print(placemarks);
Placemark placemark = placemarks[0];
//Because Placemark is a model class, properties like sublocality should be accessible
//using Dot (.) operator, you can check by erasing this .sublocality 
//and then type . to see the suggestions
String name = placemark.sublocality;
```

Comment: Thanx it works. I will mark your answer, could please tell me what does `[0]` have to do with `Placemark placemark = placemarks[0];` i believe its the first index of the list but how is it relevant here ?

Comment: @Pannam Your `placemarks` is of type `List<PlaceMark>` as you can see `List<Placemark> placemarks` here. Now, a list means it contains multiple items, here the type of item is given `Placemarks` and every such `Placemark` contains all the relevant fields. So, to access any of the `Placemark`, you've to provide the index of it to the list which you do by typing `placemarks[n]`. This will return the `Placemark` at the nth index in the list, 0 means the first item and this item will be of type `PlaceMark` as the we made the list a type of `Placemark`. And, this solves your problem.